# Can we use a variable from method of a class in another method?

Tags: python, function, class, object, return

```
class column:
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def volume(self):
        _volume = self.length*self.width*self.height **#I want to use this variable in the method below**
        print("Your result is: ")
        print(_volume)
        return self._volume

    def constituents(self):
        vol = self._volume **# here, instead of creating a new variable I want to use the previous one**
        x = int(input('ratio of cement: '))
        y = int(input('ratio of sand: '))
        z = int(input('ratio of aggregate: '))
        cement = (1.54 * (x/(x+y+z) * vol))
        sand = (1.54 * (y/(x+y+z) * vol))
        aggregate = (1.54 * (z/(x+y+z) * vol))
        print("The concrete consists of " + str(cement) + " cement " +
              str(sand) + " sand " + str(aggregate) + " aggregate.")
```

I am working in python and new to it. I want to use the volume variable (that I have defined in the function volume), in the function constituents. Now if I do the simple return thing, it gives unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'method' error. If I use parenthesis while returning the variable, it gives the RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object error.
So, I just wanted to ask if it is possible to do so. If not what is a possible solution, without creating another variable.

Comment: `vol = self.volume()`.

Comment: Note that `return self._volume` does not work either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You never set `self._volume`. If your `volume` method returned its local variable `_volume`, you would be able to get that value from `self.volume()`.

Answer (score 0):

`_volume` =/= `self._volume` - if you want a variable shared between methods of an object (like `__init__`, `volume` and `constituent s`), you need to add them to the `self.` object. You never assign anything to `self._volume`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to use volume() to set your `self._volume` property. Therefore you can change your volume() method to

```
def volume(self):
    self._volume = self.length*self.width*self.height **#I want to use this variable in the method below**
    print("Your result is: ")
    print(self._volume)
    return self._volume
```

Note that the `return self._volume` line is optional since self._volume is now accessible throughout your object.

This is basically what [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333433/can-we-use-a-variable-from-method-of-a-class-in-another-method#comment126088420_71333433) and [matszwecja](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334465/15237183) have pointed out as well.